# Noun of What a Straight Shooter Gives

Tags: phrase-requests, colloquialisms

A straight shooter gives information in an honest way.

One could say, "He (the straight shooter) gives me the ...".

Comment: The straight skinny. The real dope. An honest answer. A reliable response. What register are you looking for?

Comment: ...the _truth_, right between the eyes. Or any noun synonymous with _truth_.

Comment: I like straight skinny the most. I was looking for something that rolled off the tongue and didn't sound robotic or common.

Comment: @Tyler: Assuming you'd already implicitly defined your target "register" by using the term *straight shooter* (*straight **talker*** in my vernacular), surely the obvious phrasing is just *"He **gives it to me straight**"*. Personally though, I'd probably say *"He **tells it like it is**"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*the straight dope* was very popular, as was *the straight scoop*. Both mean **the truth.**

**the simple truth** is straightforward.

He gives me the truth *straight up* (plainly, straightforwardly).

*Straight off, straight up, straight out* are variations on the theme with subtle differences.

the [dope, poop, the skinny, low-down](http://www.synonym.com/definitions/dope/) all work as well.

There are probably dozens more.

Comment: +1 Or perhaps [**emmis**](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_yiddish_word_for_truth), the *absolute truth*. I guess that's English only in New York and Miami.